# Need help making sql data usable for math functions php

Tags: php, mysql, oop, math, web-applications

Okay, I'm trying to get data from multiple rows by user_id, then instantiate those values as separate arrays to my "Checks" class.. First I'll show you my sql setup.

```
id  user_id date    gross   net federal state   ssi other_pay   other_deduct    other_tax_deduct    company check_no
 1    1  2012-07-26 434.88  354.39  40.70   15.71   18.27   0.00    6.31            0.00                K-VA-TT   3209181
2   1   2012-08-16  433.11  353.09  39.44   15.61   18.19   0.00    6.28    0.00    K-VA-TT 3230201
```

(kind of clustered, but you get the point. I had a picture, but it wouldn't let me post it..)

Okay, now the code I'm using to call the data into PHP.

```
public function get_field($user) {
    global $database;
    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM ".static::$tablename." WHERE user_id=".$user);
    $field_data = array();
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $field_data[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }
    return $field_data;
}
```

And as many of you have probably guessed, how I receive the data from above function.

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [user_id] => 1 [date] => 2012-07-26 [gross] => 434.88 [net] => 354.39 [federal] => 40.70 [state] => 15.71 [ssi] => 18.27 [other_pay] => 0.00 [other_deduct] => 6.31 [other_tax_deduct] => 0.00 [company] => K-VA-TT [check_no] => 3209181 ) Array ( [id] => 2 [user_id] => 1 [date] => 2012-08-16 [gross] => 433.11 [net] => 353.09 [federal] => 39.44 [state] => 15.61 [ssi] => 18.19 [other_pay] => 0.00 [other_deduct] => 6.28 [other_tax_deduct] => 0.00 [company] => K-VA-TT [check_no] => 3230201 )
```

I would like that to end up in my class like

```
public date = array(2012-07-26, 2012-08-16);
public $gross = array(434.88, 433.11)
ect..
```

I don't know if I need to retrieve the data differently or just format it after. I've tried embedded for loops, while loops, foreach, and just can't seem to get it right. I also have an Instantiate function

```
private static function instantiate($record) {
    $class_name = get_called_class();
    $object     = new $class_name;

    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value) {
        if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

which uses

```
private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    // get_object_vars returns an associative array with all attributes
    // (incl. private ones!) as the keys and their current values as the value
    $object_vars = get_object_vars($this);
    // we don't care about the value, we just want to know if the key exists
    // will return true or false
    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);  
}
```

, and I've tried messing with those to get them to work with arrays, but with no luck there either. I assume that's because if one of the beginning pieces to this puzzle is missing, the rest wont fit together either. I'm at a loss here. As I said before, I'm trying to get them in to class variables so I can perform math on them (i.e. total, average, ect..) It's for a budgeting app I'm developing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if it's a whole other way of doing this that may be less confusing for me, I'll at least give it a try. If you need any more information, feel free to ask. The two functions I didn't show are pretty much self explanatory. Thanks again!

Comment: tip: you don't need the `$index++` hack. In PHP, `$arr[]=$x` will append `$x` as a new element in `$arr`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: And, please stop using global state in your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the comment about the global state? It's just an alternative to using $database = new DatabaseObject in this case. I'm fairly new to PHP though, so I'm ignorant about the difference/risks.

Answer (score 0):

This change of code should do the trick for you :

```
$date = array();
$gross= array();
// all the other columns.........like this

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $date[] = $row['date'];
    $gross[] = $row['gross'];
    // other columns ...... like this
}

$filled_data =array ();
$filled_data[] =$date;
$filled_data[]=$gross;
// other arrays ...........

return $filled_data;
```

Comment: After swapping that out and making the variables in your example into class variables, I kept getting a "Catchable fatal error: Object of class Checks could not be converted to string at line 161". 

Line 161 happened to be "$filled_data[] =$this->gross;

Even though I wasn't calling for gross, I was calling for net, I was still using the function. I'm not sure why it spit out that error at all. I can't see anything being put into a string with that syntax, but I'm no expert either.

Comment: Anyway, so I commented out the whole $filter_data portion of the function, and it in fact instantiates all the values the way I wanted. Honestly I'm not sure what the purpose of the $filled_data portion of the function was for, but if you'd care to elaborate, I'm sure I could find use for it. Thanks for your help by the way, you're a lifesaver!! :) (Sorry, it was too much for one comment xD)

Comment: @kyle filled data was used to *merge* all the variables in one array for easy returning from this function , that's all :)